# Transparency in image as plane

Tags: modeling

In blender 2.8 when brought in as a reference or background, .png file, the transparent layer is retained however if broght in as a plane the transparent layer is not respected and the whole image is rendered.

Is this true or am I missing something? Please keep in mind that I'm a newbie and looking for a relevently easy fix.

Thank you.

---

Here's the file the comments don't allow you to post a picture [image]

Comment: It should work... maybe share your PNG file...

Comment: Here's the png file I used. If you say that it should work maybe I'll make another test file to try it out.

Comment: As I said I would do I made 2 new png files and neither one of them retained the transparently.

Comment: mmh weird because it works correctly for me, both Add > Image > Reference and Add > Image > Background

Comment: Could be worse.  I tried "image as plane" and not only was Alpha not working but other things were messed up, too.  Changing the settings for transparency (always look for such settings in eeVee) did not fix things.  I assume bugs in the beta code.  In my case, I could easily use a solid background to match and re-exported the PNG without an alpha channel.

Answer (score 8):

In 2.81

I needed to tick "Use Alpha" and was able to use transparency.
[image: BLENDER 2.81]

Comment: Studies have been conducted on the readability and legibility of all caps text. Scientific testing from the 20th century onwards has generally indicated that all caps text is less legible and readable than lower-case text. In addition, switching to all caps may make text appear hectoring and obnoxious for cultural reasons, since all-capitals is often used in transcribed speech to indicate that the speaker is shouting. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps)

Answer (score 5):

You are probably trying to work with Eevee and getting Black where the alpha shows through on the image in the Image Editor. In the Material Shader properties, change from Opaque to Alpha Blend. If you use Cycles, the alpha will work as expected immediately though.

[image]

Comment: Just tested, worked well.           Thanks!