# Why is the image not transparent in when I import as a plane?

Tags: import, image, transparency, 2d

I'm very new to blender and I'm trying to make a simple character with a 2d face. I was following along with this tutorial (https://youtu.be/YGjwOEMgDGw?t=60) but I can't get my image to look transparent.

[image: The whole image is black with white outline around everything that's not transparent]

This is what it looks like in the blender image editor. The transparency shows up in that view.

[image: Image editor showing image has alpha]

The starting Shader setup is also different from the tutorial (I don't know enough to know what all this means)

[image: Showing different Shader set up]

But when I make it like the tutorial it looks like this, still not transparent (it also looks like in the image editor if I set the alpha to none).

[image: The images black is shiny and theres a wierd white box]
[image]

I have no idea what settings I might have wrong or what I'm doing wrong. I've been stuck for about 2 hours on this so any help would be appreciated. I used photoshop to make the image (just incase there is some setting I need to set there), and also here are the import settings for the image.

[image: import settings the alpha is set to straight]

Again any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you imported your image by first creating an image plane (Add > Image > Background), then you will want to click on the resulting plane object in Object Mode, and then look in the *Object Data* tab of the Properties Panel to find its **Opacity** slider.

[image]

If you created it as a Background Image, you will want to select your camera instead (this is easiest to do in the *Outliner* window), and then look in the same Object Data tab from the Properties Panel, which will now show the object data for the camera. This will expose you to a different opacity slider.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm trying to use the image plane, but the object data for that doesn't have the picture icon. it instead has a triangle with squares are each corner and no group of settings that look similar to the first picture. I also tried the background image and that one was transparent, but it still had a white outline. I want to use a image plane object and not a background image. is there something else I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my own answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136134/transparency-in-image-as-plane). I wasn't asking the right question or at least wasn't asking it well. I was using Eevee instead of cycles. didn't even know those things were important.